# Purpose of this R idiom (match.call followed by eval(parent.frame())

Tags: r

I've inherited some code that uses what I think is a common R idiom for libraries, but I'm not sure what is achieved by writing in such a verbose way. Ultimately I intend to re-write but I would first like to know why before I do something stupid.

```
ecd <-
function(formula, data, subset, weights, offset, ...) {
    cl = match.call()
    mf = match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
    m =
        match(c("formula", "data", "subset", "weights", "offset"),
              names(mf),
              0L)
    mf = mf[c(1L, m)]
    mf$drop.unused.levels = TRUE
    mf[[1L]] = quote(stats::model.frame)
    mf = eval(mf, parent.frame())
    mt = attr(mf, "terms")
    y = stats::model.response(mf, "numeric")
    w = as.vector(stats::model.weights(mf))

    offset = as.vector(stats::model.offset(mf))

    x = stats::model.matrix(mt, mf, contrasts)
    z = ecd.fit(x, y, w, offset, ...)
```

My current understanding is that it constructs a function call object (type?) from the original arguments to the function and then manually calls it, rather than just calling `stats::model.frame` directly. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: `eval(mf,parent.frame())` is getting `mf` from the suitable environment.

Comment: I thought it was calling `mf` in the parent environment, no?

Comment: `eval evaluates the expr argument in the environment specified by envir and returns the computed value. If envir is not specified, then the default is parent.frame() (the environment where the call to eval was made).` From the docs(`help("eval")`).

Comment: Yes, so it's *evaluating* `mf` in the parent environment, it gets `mf` the usual way (as a function argument from the enclosing frame), and then returns the value of evaluating `mf` in the parent frame (and then assigns it to a variable called `mf`... well, I didn't write this). Unless of course by "getting `mf`" you mean assigning the variable (the "new" `mf`), in which case I think we are in agreement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this should answer everything, explanations are in the code :

```
# for later
FOO <- function(x) 1000 * x
y <- 1

foo <- function(...) {
  cl = match.call()
  message("cl")
  print(cl)
  message("as.list(cl)")
  print(as.list(cl))
  message("class(cl)")
  print(class(cl))
  # we can modify the call is if it were a list
  cl[[1]] <- quote(FOO)
  message("modified call")
  print(cl)
  y <- 2
  # now I want to call it,  if I call it here or in the parent.frame might
  # give a different output
  message("evaluate it locally")
  print(eval(cl))
  message("evaluate it in the parent environment")
  print(eval(cl, parent.frame()))
  message("eval.parent is equivalent and more idiomatic")
  print(eval.parent(cl))
  invisible(NULL)
}
foo(y)

# cl
# foo(y)
# as.list(cl)
# [[1]]
# foo
# 
# [[2]]
# y
# 
# class(cl)
# [1] "call"
# modified call
# FOO(y)
# evaluate it locally
# [1] 2000
# evaluate it in the parent environment
# [1] 1000
# eval.parent is equivalent and more idiomatic
# [1] 1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the code, I'm also keen to understand why you would do this? As far as I can see it makes the code harder to read and understand, and possible exposes you to strange effects from outside the function? The explanation I've heard for this kind of NSE is just to grab the variable names for plot labels.

Comment: I don't think the code is very clean, it's not commented and `mf` is not the same kind of object depending on where you look and has a cryptic name. It might have been clearer to call `stats::model.frame` in the function directly without doing a substitution.

Comment: Substitutions on the first element of `match.call()` have this advantage that you're explicitly taking exactly the same arguments as the original call. with `stats::model.frame(formula, data, subset, weights, offset, ...)` you're typing these variables twice so you will have to update in both places if something change, and the next reader has to compare visually to note that you're passing the same argument as in the original call.

Comment: Moreover if the function supports missing arguments you'll have problems (if `subset` is missing for instance, the above call will fail), this could be handled with adequate `if (missing(subset)){...}` etc but it's more verbose.

Comment: Thanks, I think that answers everything.